# Is it possible to perform fast 48-bit unsigned multiplication in JavaScript without bignums?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, bit-manipulation

In JavaScript, we can perform 48-bit addition, subtraction, division and modulus:

```
In JavaScript, we can perform 48-bit addition, subtraction, division and modulus, using the native Number type:

function u48_add(a, b) {
  return (a + b) % Math.pow(2, 48);
}

function u48_sub(a, b) {
  return (a - b + Math.pow(2,48)) % Math.pow(2, 48);
}

function u48_div(a, b) {
  return Math.floor(a / b);
}

function u48_mod(a, b) {
  return a % b;
}
```

All these operations work, because the intermediate values can't pass `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. For multiplication, though, they could:

```
function u48_mul(a, b) {
  return (a * b) % Math.pow(2, 48);
}
```

So `u48_mul` could return incorrect results. A solution would be to use BigInt:

```
function u48_mul(a, b) {
  return Number((BigInt(a) * BigInt(b)) % (2n ** 48n));
}
```

But, in most browsers, it is drastically slower. Is there any clever trick that allows us to perform 48-bit unsigned multiplication in JavaScript faster?

Comment: But are intermediate values greater than 2^53 reasonably expected? Also in your bigInt example I think you will loose precicision by coercing to  Number again

Comment: @johnSmith yes, but the point is getting the correct result, modulus `2 ** 48`. That's how `uint32` works, for example: you also lose precision when multiplying two `uint32` in C, but the result is still correct modulus `2 ** 32`. The wrong `u48_mul` can actually give you incorrect results, that are off by 1 or 2.

Comment: It's tricky because Javascript binary operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a, b >= 0, if you write a and b as radix 2<sup>24</sup> integers you have
a = a<sub>1</sub>⋅2<sup>24</sup> + a<sub>0</sub> and b = b<sub>1</sub>⋅2<sup>24</sup> + b<sub>0</sub>,
0 <= a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>0</sub> < 2<sup>24</sup>.

In this form a⋅b = a<sub>1</sub>⋅b<sub>1</sub>⋅2<sup>48</sup> + (a<sub>1</sub>⋅b<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>⋅b<sub>1</sub>)⋅2<sup>24</sup> + a<sub>0</sub>⋅b<sub>0</sub>. Now taking this mod 2<sup>48</sup> causes the first term to become 0. Products like a<sub>1</sub>⋅b<sub>0</sub> are the multiplication of two 24-bit integers, so multiplied as JS numbers produces the exact 48-bit result. Adding two such values together may produce a 49-bit value, but that is still < 2<sup>53</sup> and thus exact. Since we're going to be multiplying by 2<sup>24</sup> we need only retain the low-order 24 bits of this sum. That's good because when we AND (&) it with a 24-bit mask JS will keep only the low order 32-bits. Finally we add the result to a<sub>0</sub>⋅b<sub>0</sub>, another 48-bit value. The result may exceed 2<sup>48</sup> and if it does then we'll just subtract 2<sup>48</sup>.

```js
function mulmod48(a, b) {
    const two_to_the_24th = 16777216;
    const two_to_the_48th = two_to_the_24th * two_to_the_24th;
    const mask24 = two_to_the_24th - 1;

    let a0 = a & mask24;
    let a1 = (a - a0) / two_to_the_24th;
    let b0 = b & mask24;
    let b1 = (b - b0) / two_to_the_24th;
    let t1 = ((a1 * b0 + a0 * b1) & mask24) * two_to_the_24th;
    let result = t1 + a0 * b0;
    if (result >= two_to_the_48th) {
        result -= two_to_the_48th;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This can be improved by eliminating one of the divisions by 2<sup>24</sup>, thanks to an observation by @Mark Dickinson. Although IEEE 754 binary64 floats can represent exactly all integers between -2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup>, those are not the only integers that can be represented exactly. In particular a 48 or 49 bit integer multiplied by a power of 2 within the specified IEEE 754 exponent range can also be represented exactly. Thus we can replace these five lines

```py
    let a0 = a & mask24;
    let a1 = (a - a0) / two_to_the_24th;
    let b0 = b & mask24;
    let b1 = (b - b0) / two_to_the_24th;
    let t1 = ((a1 * b0 + a0 * b1) & mask24) * two_to_the_24th;
```

with these three

```py
    let a0 = a & mask24;
    let b0 = b & mask24;
    let t1 = ((((a - a0) * b0 + a0 * (b - b0)) / two_to_the_24th) & mask24) * two_to_the_24th;
```

since both `(a - a0)` and `(b - b0)` are multiples of 2<sup>24</sup> so must the products of these with `b0` and `a0` and therefore so must the sum of these products. In other words, both `(a - a0)` and `(b - b0)` have only 24 *significant* bits, so the products have only 48 significants bits and the sum of those has only 49 significant bits.

Now, is this any faster than using Bigints? In an experiment on `Chrome 96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (x86_64)` it was almost 6x faster than your BigInt version of `u48_mul`.

Comment: Oh, I was just wondering if there was some simple solution I was missing. I now feel bad for the amount of work you put in answering my question. That is extremely impressive. Wish I could tip this answer. Thank you.

Comment: I enjoy working on these little problems, so thank you for asking your question.

Comment: @MaiaVictor "Wish I could tip this answer" --> [wish granted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: You could save a division by dividing `(a1 * b0 + a0 * b1)` by `two_to_the_24th` instead of dividing each of `a1` and `b1` individually.

Comment: Well, `a1 * b0 + a0 * b1` would be performed using IEEE 754 arithmetic as usual. It would indeed potentially be larger than 2**48, but it would still be computed exactly, since `a1` and `b1` and the result would all be exact integer multiples of `2**24`. So the overflow wouldn't cause incorrect results.

Comment: Agreed about the shift operators. The divide-mask-multiply in the `let t1` line could probably be replaced with a modulo operator, though - the high part of the result is `((a-a0) * b0 + a0 * (b - b0)) % (two_to_the_48th)`.  (Again, intermediate results would be greater than 2**48, but there wouldn't be any floating-point rounds.)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Yep. Sorry, looks like I was unclear (and it was a minor point anyway (and I've already upvoted)). My original suggestion is essentially: replace your `let a1 = ...` line with `let a1 = (a - a0);`, and similarly for `let b1 = ...`. Then the `let t1` line becomes: `let t1 = (((a1 * b0 + a0 * b1) / two_to_the_24th) & mask24) * two_to_the_24th;`.  But after that, I think you can further simplify to `let t1 = (a1 * b0 + a0 * b1) % two_to_the_48th;`, which may or may not be faster.

Comment: Yes, the product could be as large as `2**72`, but it would be an integral multiple of `2**24`, so it only has 48 _significant_ bits and would be exactly representable in the IEEE 754 binary64 format that JavaScript uses for its `Number` type. IOW, all the arithmetic would still be exact and the end result would be exactly correct.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Aha, I finally understand what you're saying! I forgot about the exponent in IEEE 754. I will try this out when I get back, and do some timings, and make the changes if it all works out. Thanks.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica but that's only rep, not money...